# Javascript - revealing object and variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, inheritance, scope

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLH7J/1/

What the jsFiddle and code below shows are two examples that essentially do the same thing. When trying to call `first();` or `this.first();` in either example, an undefined error is thrown. I can call the functions later through the instance, but not when trying to instantiate the object using `init(){...}()` like a constructor. I put init() at the bottom thinking it was an order of operations thing, but that is not the case. This does not work the way I thought it would work.

I am curious to understand how this is supposed to be done, and why this cannot be done.

```
//create and return an obj
var fishSticks = function(){
    return {
        first: function(){
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML="Success";
        },
        init: function(){
            try{
                first(); //err
                this.first(); // also err
             }catch(e){
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=e.toString();
            }
        }()
    }
}   

//do function stuff and then return 'this'
var fishFillet = function(){
    var first = function(){
            document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML="Success";
    }
    var init = function(){
            try{
                first(); //err
                this.first(); // also err
             }catch(e){
                 document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML=e.toString();
            }
    }()
return this;
}

 var test = new fishSticks();    
 var test2 = new fishFillet();
```

​

Comment: In the second example, you'll never be able to call `test2.init()` or `test2.first()`.  They're not properties of any object.

Comment: In the second example, calling `first();` inside `init` should work. But the whole construct does not seem to make a lot of sense to me. Why are not using a simple constructor and directly execute the code in there? What is your overall goal?

Comment: I would only need `test2.init()` to fire once to fire once, when creating the obj, like a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand two things:

1) JavaScript does not automatically insert `this` like Java does, so the `first()` call will only look through the lexical scope for a definition of `first`, it will nok look at the `this` object. Therefore the call to `first()` should work but `this` will be bound to something else than what you might expect inside `first`.

2) Local variables in a constructor do not become members of the constructed object.

Comment: I learned oop in Java; it may be showing. Thanks, this helps my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, if you comment out the call in "init" to `this.first()` then you get the "Success" message.

The first version doesn't work because JavaScript simply does not allow for references to be made within an under-construction object to the object itself.  There's just no way to do it.

The second one works (well the simple reference to "first" works) because "first" is declared as a local variable. Local variables are **not** properties of any object, and in particular they're not properties of the object allocated when the function is called with `new`.  That's why `this.first()` doesn't work.

In the second one, you could make `this.first()` work by declaring things differently:

```
var fishFillet = function(){
    this.first = function(){
            document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML="Success";
    }
    var init = function(){
            try{
                this.first(); //will work
             }catch(e){
                 document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML=e.toString();
            }
    }()
    return this;
}
```

Also, for what it's worth, the weird anti-pattern of

```
var something = function() { ... }
```

is not as useful as

```
function something() { ... }
```

There's no reason to use the `var` declaration instead of the `function` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
var fishFillet = function () {
    var first = function () {
        document.write( 'Success' );
    };

    var init = function () {
        first();
    };

    init();

    return {
        first: first
    };
};
```

And then:

```
var ff = fishFillet(); // calls init() which calls first()
ff.first(); // call first() manually
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uaCnv/

So, first you define all your functions, next you manually invoke `init`, and last you return an object containing those functions which should be available through the resulting object (as methods).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using both as a constructor, format them as such:

```
function fishFillet(){
    this.first = function(){
        document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML="Success";
    }
    this.init = function(){
        try{
            this.first();
        }catch(e){
            document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML=e.toString();
        }
    }
}
var food = new fishFillet();
food.init();
```

The reason it wasn't working for you is b/c "first" is created as a local varaible, and is deleted after execultion. Init isn't being called until after the execution of the constructor has finished

Comment: I did not know `var vars` would be deleted, which makes the difference between `this.vars` and `var vars = ...` then `return this`  quite significant.